# Any ideas how to setup geocoder with rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder, geocoder

I am trying to get latitude and longitude from address but when I run rails db:seed latitude and longitude stay blank and the rest of the fields will be seeded

here is my model

```
    attr_accessor :lat, :lng
    geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
    after_save :geocode, if: ->(building){ building.address.present? }
```

and I have gem 'geocoder' in GemFile

```
    My Rails version 5.0.6
    and ruby version 2.4.1
```

Note: I need to use only 'geocoder' gem
That's all I have, thanks in advance

Comment: How does your database schema for this model look like? Is there a `lat` and `lng` column in that table?

Comment: yes I do have both lat and lng. their type is float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after_save` means geocoding is done after the record is saved to the database and therefore the geocoding information itself is not saved into the database.

Furthermore `attr_accessor :lat, :lng` overrides the getter and setter methods provided by Rails for the `lat` and `lng` database columns.

Just change your code to:

```
# remove this line: attr_accessor :lat, :lng
geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
before_save :geocode, if: ->(building){ building.address.present? }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my night :)